# Select rows from matrix by matching character vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix of genes (rows) and expression values for different samples (columns). The matrix has 25 000 rows, but I only want to select some of them. I want to find and keep rows that start with a specific string, see example below. Package scater vas used to generate matrix with get_exprs().

This is a sample of the matrix:

```
> get_exprs(sce,"exprs")[1:3,1:3]
               Bams.A10_R1.out.bam Bams.A11_R1.out.bam Bams.A12_R1.out.bam
ENSSSCG00000030218       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06
ENSSSCG00000029697       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06
ENSSSCG00000027726       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06
```

I create a vector with the strings I am interested in and try to index those rows, **it works**:

```
> endo.markers<-c("ENSSSCG00000030218","ENSSSCG00000029697")
> get_exprs(sce,"exprs")[endo.markers,1:3]

               Bams.A10_R1.out.bam Bams.A11_R1.out.bam Bams.A12_R1.out.bam
ENSSSCG00000030218       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06
ENSSSCG00000029697       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06       -2.885387e-06
```

However, when I include **all** genes that I am interested in, I get following error:

```
> endo.markers<-scan("endo.markers.txt",character())
> get_exprs(sce,"exprs")[endo.markers,1:3]
```

> Error in get_exprs(sce, "exprs")[endo.markers, 1:3] : 
>     subscript out of bounds

I believe the reason for this is that all genes I am interested in, i.e. all elements of my vector endo.markers, are not present in the matrix. Any other ideas or solutions? The vector seems to be ok, attached below.

```
> scan("endo.markers.txt",character())
Read 46 items
 [1] "ENSSSCG00000012909" "ENSSSCG00000007675" "ENSSSCG00000015622" "ENSSSCG00000005625"
 [5] "ENSSSCG00000009320" "ENSSSCG00000008844" "ENSSSCG00000003950" "ENSSSCG00000007115"
 [9] "ENSSSCG00000008294" "ENSSSCG00000017277" "ENSSSCG00000015116" "ENSSSCT00000036466"
[13] "ENSSSCG00000005122" "ENSSSCG00000003527" "ENSSSCG00000030642" "ENSSSCG00000015753"
[17] "ENSSSCG00000021443" "ENSSSCG00000001695" "ENSSSCG00000005096" "ENSSSCG00000013297"
[21] "ENSSSCG00000017296" "ENSSSCG00000010404" "ENSSSCG00000013302" "ENSSSCG00000003017"
[25] "ENSSSCG00000006035" "ENSSSCG00000007927" "ENSSSCG00000015579" "ENSSSCG00000016504"
[29] "ENSSSCG00000012277" "ENSSSCG00000001404" "ENSSSCG00000008953" "ENSSSCG00000017164"
[33] "ENSSSCG00000017723" "ENSSSCG00000007436" "ENSSSCG00000013655" "ENSSSCG00000005533"
[37] "ENSSSCG00000027850" "ENSSSCG00000006862" "ENSSSCG00000025698" "ENSSSCG00000016009"
[41] "ENSSSCG00000016450" "ENSSSCG00000002039" "ENSSSCG00000006288" "ENSSSCG00000016174"
[45] "ENSSSCG00000002829" "ENSSSCG00000012909"
```

Comment: From which package is the function `get_exprs()`? ok, you have to reduce the set of all endo.markers which you interested in to those present as rownames in your matrx. `endo.markers %in% row.names(...)` gives you a vector of logical values which you can use as index for `endo.markers` to do the reduction.

Comment: package is scater. Great, got the vector with logical values. How do I use it to create new endo.genes vector with only TRUE values? In this case it is easy to just remove the FALSE manually, but in larger vectors that might me difficult.

Comment: `ind <- endo.markers %in% row.names(...); endo.markers.reduced <- endo.markers[ind]` or short `endo.markers.reduced <- endo.markers[endo.markers %in% row.names(...)]` Now `all(endo.markers.reduced %in% row.names(...))` gives `TRUE`

Comment: Great, it works, thanks!